# Can't create a FB ad using PHP graph API anyway (cURL)

Tags: php, facebook, curl, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I spend a few days trying to create a Facebook ad using Business Marketing API. Even tried to use pure cURL. The problem is that image is succesfully uploading and I can back an image cache but when I try to create ad, I got an error "Image or Video Required". Please help me to create an ad. Have no idea anymore. Thanks

````
    $image->{AdImageFields::FILENAME} = './test.png';

    $image->create();
    $hashi = $image->{AdImageFields::HASH};
  $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/act_".$ad_account_id."/adcreatives?locale=en_US");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "object_url=".$_POST['link']."&body=".$_POST['body']."&title=".$_POST['title']."&name=".$_POST['name']."&image_hash=".$hashi."&access_token=".$access_token  
            );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
   $creative = new AdCreative(null, 'act_'.$ad_account_id);
    $creative->setData(array(
      AdCreativeFields::TITLE => $_POST['title'],
      AdCreativeFields::BODY => $_POST['body'],
      AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_URL => $_POST['link'],
      AdCreativeFields::IMAGE_HASH => $hashi,
    ));
    $creative->create();
    // Finally, create your ad along with ad creative.
    // Please note that the ad creative is not created independently, rather its
    // data structure is appended to the ad group
    $ad = new Ad(null, 'act_'.$ad_account_id)
    $ad->setData(array(
      AdFields::NAME => $_POST['name'],
      AdFields::ADSET_ID => (int)$_POST['adgrid'],
      AdFields::CREATIVE => array("creative_id" => $creative->id),
    ));
    $ad->create(array(
      Ad::STATUS_PARAM_NAME => Ad::STATUS_PAUSED,
    ));    
}```
````

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: @Lulu unfortunately no